# tcpdump: invalid file size

Tags: linux, networking, tcpdump, platform

I am trying to run a tcpdump command with filesize 4096 but, it return with an error :-

tcpdump: invalid filesize

Command :- tcpdump -i any -nn -tttt -s0 -w %d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S:%s_hostname_ipv6.pcap -G 60 -C 4096 port 53

After some hit & trial I found that it's failing for filesize (4096 i.e 2^12) (8192 i.e. 2^13) and so on.

So, for filesize after 2^11 it's giving me invalid filesize error.

Can anybody tell me on which condition tcpdump return invalid filesize.

Also when I was running with Filesize :- 100000

tcpdump -i any -nn -tttt -s0 -w %d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S:%s_hostname_ipv6.pcap -G 60 -C 100000 port 53

.pcap file of max size 1.3GB was getting created.

I also tried looking in the source code of tcpdump but, couldn't find much.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to run a tcpdump command with filesize 4096

To quote a recent version of the tcpdump man page:

```
   -C file_size
          Before writing a raw packet to a  savefile,  check  whether  the
          file  is  currently  larger than file_size and, if so, close the
          current savefile and open a new one.  Savefiles after the  first
          savefile  will  have the name specified with the -w flag, with a
          number after it, starting at 1 and continuing upward.  The units
          of  file_size  are  millions  of  bytes  (1,000,000  bytes,  not
          1,048,576 bytes).
```

So `-C 4096` means a file size of 4096000000 bytes.  That's a large file size and, in older versions of tcpdump, a file size that large (one bigger than 2147483647) isn't supported for the `-C` flag.

If you mean you want it to write out files that are 4K *bytes* in size, unfortunately tcpdump doesn't support that.  This means it's past due to fix [tcpdump issue 884](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/884) by merging [tcpdump pull request 916](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/pull/916) - I'll do that now, but that won't help you now.

> Also when I was running with Filesize :- 100000

That's a file size of 100000000000, which is 100 gigabytes.  Unfortunately, if you want a file size of 100000 bytes (100 kilobytes), again, the current minimum file size is 1 megabyte, so that's not supported.

Comment: But, when I run tcpdump with filesize of 5000 then tcpdump was started and it didn't give any error like this "tcpdump: invalid filesize".
Can you please give some clarification regarding that.

Also After some hit & trial I found that it's failing for filesize (4096 i.e 2^12) (8192 i.e. 2^13) and so on.

So, for filesize after 2^11 it's giving me invalid filesize error.

Comment: "Can you please give some clarification regarding that." Yes - to coin a phrase, "overflows happen".  pre-4.10 versions of tcpdump just do `Cflag = atoi(the argument) * 1000000;` and report an error if and only if the resulting value of `CFlag` is < 0.  If `CFlag` is an `int`, as it is in pre-1.9 versions of tcpdump, and the result *happens* to have the uppermost bit set, it's negative; if it's a `long`, as it is in 1.9.x, it gets sign extended, which means the same thing happens.  1.10 fixed the test to work correctly.

Comment: "So, for filesize after 2^11 it's giving me invalid filesize error. "  5000 > 2048, so, no, it's not giving you "invalid file size" (yes, there's a space between "file" and "size") for all values > 2^11.

Comment: No it's filesize not file size. 
If possible please you also try on your system if the same behaviour is observed.

Comment: "No it's filesize not file size. If possible please you also try on your system if the same behaviour is observed."  I did, and it says "file size".  I also looked at the source code to all versions of tcpdump from 0.7 through 1.10, and they say "file size".

Comment: Hmm, yes you were correct. But, I am unable to understand the reason behind this error.

Comment: The reason is that 1) no released version of tcpdump allows you to set the file size less than 1 megabyte (1 000 000 bytes, not 1024*1024 bytes), because they multiple the argument to `-C` by 1000000 and 2) in versions of tcpdump before 4.99, that multiplication can produce a 32-bit value whose upper bit is set and that thus looks like a negative number, causing tcpdump to report "invalid file size".